# Unity - Issue with Android Java JAR inclusion

Tags: java, android, jar, unity-game-engine

I have included a Java Jar "Assets/Plugins/Android/" however I am not able to use it properly in my Unity App.

I have verified I called into the Jar but the Jar fails.  I have determined it is due to the Jar including a text file in it. When I use this JAR and build via Android Build tools the files are put in "com/name/name/text.file".  In Unity it doesn't unpackage these files from the Jar into the folders like the Android Build tools.

Am I doing something wrong in Unity? Do I need to put the JAR in a different location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to place the file at "Assets/Plugins/Android/com/name/name/text.file". If that doesn't work you might be able to use a post-processing build script to open up the .apk file and add the missing file to the appropriate location and then resign and realign it.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html

Comment: I am building a plugin to distribute. Would I be able to use the post-processing build script to inject the folder and sub folders/files during APK creation without user intervention?  Or would that have to be a menu item in Unity my users have to remember to do?

Comment: Unfortunately, the user would have to build their project with the interface you set up. The Unity Manual's example has it as a button in   a menu tab titled "My Tools".

Comment: Actually the approach of including them in Assets/Plugins/Android doesn't work :( Unity ignores our folders and files placed there. They don't ever get inserted into the APK unless we are doing something wrong.